# Dynamically changing Texture2D

Tags: c#, textures

```
private void occupiedcheck(Vector2 positionv, Texture2D positiont)
   {
       int xpos=(((int)positionv.X+100)/150);
       int ypos=(((int)positionv.Y+110)/150);
       for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
       {
           if (piecexarray[j] == xpos && pieceyarray[j] == ypos)
           {

           }
           else
           {
               positiont = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/Highlighter");
               break;
           }
       }
   }
```

Above you can see a function I've written for a C# game, I want it to change the texture that is passed into it (Texture2D positiont) to "Graphics/Highlighter", when the 'else' part of the function is activated. Currently it doesn't work, how can I get it so that I can pass an existing Texture2D into the function and change it dynamically via the 'Content.Load' method within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method parameter keyword in your method so that "[[a]ny changes made to the parameter in the method will be reflected in that variable when control passes back to the calling method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)":

```
private void occupiedcheck(Vector2 positionv, ref Texture2D positiont)
{
    // ...
}
```